# How shall I declare Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

Which form is preferred:

```
String my = "Which form shall I use?";
Iterator iter = my.iterator();
```

or

```
Iterator<String> iter = my.iterator();
```

I personally preferr the former but in my materials from uni they use the latter.

Comment: String has no method iterator().

Comment: Why do you prefer the former? The latter is more type-safe. Btw, a String is not iterable.

Comment: Meaningless. The question is based on a false premiss.

Comment: @Jesper I prefer the former for the reason that there is less typing. And why on earth String isn't "iterable"? Seriously what's the reason behind it? Isn't String just another container? What would be illogical in having iterator which would allow me iterate over it? I just don't get it.

Comment: @EJP I really don't understand what you mean. If you saying so because of the <String> just put anything ("iterable") there.

Comment: Why `String` is not iterable: Ask the people who designed the standard Java libraries...

Comment: As your code doesn't compile, asking which form of it is preferable is entirely pointless, and asking a question where people have to make substitutions to make it make sense ditto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the latter form, the Iterator is strongly typed which is preferable

Answer (score 7):

You should use generics when the API provides it. That is, the latter alternative is preferrable.

```
Iterator iter = someList.iterator();
String s = (String) iter.next();  // prone to class cast exceptions.
                                  // What if someone for instance accidentally
                                  // put a CharSequence in the list?
```

vs

```
Iterator<String> iter = someList.iterator();
String s = iter.next();           // guaranteed typesafe at compile-time.
```

(String does not implement `Iterable<String>` however, but I'm sure you meant something like `List<String> my = Arrays.asList("Which form shall I use?")`

Answer (score 5):

The latter.  The generic argument avoids explicit casts, and helps you maintain type-safety.  However, String is not Iterable.

Answer (score 2):

String is not iterable? If you want to iterate over the characters you need to do something like this:

```
String my = "Which form shall I use?";
for(char c : my.toCharArray())
    System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: true, the char array is iterable, but not the string itself (a string has-a char array, but it isn't one)